# Importar XML no Mysql

Tags: mysql, xml, codificação-de-caracteres

Possuo dois arquivos em xml.

Quando importo um deles vem assim `pÃºblica` e o outro vem assim `pública`

Abri os arquivos no notepad++ e na aba Formatar os dois arquivos estão com Codificação em UTF-8(sem BOM).

Como resolvo este problema?

Comment: Quando abre os dois arquivos no notepad++ os dois aparecem com acentuação correta estando em UTF-8(sem BOM)

Comment: Descobri, o problema eram os arquivo de onde eu gerava estes dois novos arquivos. Um deles estava com ANSI. vlw man